# NHibernate, map a field to a table in another database

Tags: nhibernate

I would like to ask if we can map a field in a table to a table in another database?

Suppose my databases structure is as follow:

dbA -> table A -> field A

dbB -> tableB

Suppose we have ClassA and ClassB corresponding to a record in tableA and tableB, how can I write the map between fieldA and tableB so that we save tableB's name in fieldA, rather than a record in tableB?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure about the intention...

> *"...write the map between fieldA and tableB so that we save tableB's name in fieldA, rather than a record in tableB..."*

But for example with MS SQL Server, if the connection would be like:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=MySERVER;Database=dbA;...
```

we can have a mapping

```
<class name="ClassA" table="[dbo].[TableA]" ...
```

and also, if access rights will support it, we can do

```
<class name="ClassB" table="[dbB].[dbo].[TableB]" ...
```

In extreme, there could even be a linked object with its catalogue:

```
<class name="ClassC" table="[LinkedServer].[dbC].[dbo].[TableC]" ...
```

*NOTE: I am not challenging the correctness, just showing the possibility how to interact among DB and even DB Servers (linked object) while using one/single connection*